How can libraries be used for all pages in quarto book generated using R markdown
I have a simple quarto book that I created using RStudio. I have several pages, say:

data.qmd
results.qmd

If within data.qmd I called some packages, for example:
library(minfi)
library(tidyverse)

It seems that these packages need to now be called separately within results.qmd, as when I call

quarto render

It gives me an error when it is working on results.qmd as it can't find those packages when it needs them. In other words, it seems that each page is like a separate R markdown "unit".
Why is this and is there a way to have the packages work on all pages when being rendered?
Thank you!

It seems that there exists not a really satisfying solution: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3250
